# Definindo parametros e filtrando arquivo .TXT

Tags: python-3.x, txt, filtro, xls

Tenho um arquivo com separador `|` em arquivo .txt, gostaria de transformá-lo em arquivo `.xls` e então trabalhar com ele por meio de filtragem e substituição de valores em python3.

E possível ?!

Segue um modelo do arquivo ".txt":

|0000|005|0|||01072019|31072019|MODELO|15684294000195|SP|5107040||00|2|

Comment: Você pode utilizar a biblioteca pandas para fazer isso. Não seria preciso mudar o tipo do arquivo para realizar filtros e tudo mais, só no final você iria escolher a saída.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para trabalhar com dados tabulados você pode utilizar a bibliotecas pandas.
utilize o comando abaixo para instala-la, caso não tenha.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pandas
```

E como um exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

tabela = pd.read_fwf("seuArquivo.txt", delimiter="|")
tabela.to_excel('salvarArquivo.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
```

Comment: Obrigado Murilo, o que me diz de jogar uma formula de EXCEL no script para que ao converter o arquivo .TXT ja vir editado no arquivo output ?

Comment: @IvanAlmeida não entendi, vc fala de colocar uma formula no seu arquivo txt, assim na hora que converter para planilha já vir com a fórmula? É uma boa ideia, eu particularmente nunca precisei utilizar assim, na teoria da certo, você poderia fazer um teste! Obs: se a resposta lhe ajudou não esqueça de marcar como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida

Comment: Segue o passo a passo que eu faco sem o script.

Comment: 1 - Importo o arquivo .TXT para o EXCEL definindo o delimitador " | " . 2- Verifico informacoes que nao sao relevantes no arquivo convertido para EXCEL. 3- Apos a indentificacao utilizo formula no excel para subistituir por dados que sao relevantes. 4-Salvo o arquivo e envio para um sistema de validacao no qual verificara se esta no formato adequado de leitura e compilacao. 5- Acaso esteja, ele aceitara e validara sem erros. OBS: Desculpas a acentuacoes, utilizo teclado em modo USA e desculpas por ter esquecido de marcar como correta !

Comment: Sendo assim, como e padrao Murilo gostaria que o script em Pyhton fizesse isso de forma automatica sem precisar ficar exportando/importando. Convertesse, Editasse, Verificasse se a dados invalidos (se houver, subistituisse por dados validos [ que eu acrecentaria ] utilizando a formula que tenho), e apresentasse no arquivo de saida. Se possivel Murilo qualquer ideia e valida. Obrigado !

Comment: Obs: Nao precisa ser necessariamente em Python : )

Comment: @IvanAlmeida entendi, da pra procurar por esses dados inválidos e já tratar antes de converter para Excel, mas para criar essa validação precisaria que você passasse um exemplo dos dados inválidos e pelo que você os substituí

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer parsing em arquivos, e cada uma funciona para uma finalidade.

i. A mais simples é user o open, que é nativo do Python.

```
my_file = []
openfile = open('file.txt')
lines = openfile.readlines()
for i in  lines:
    temp = i.split(sep="|")
    my_file.append(temp)
```

**O método readlines é muito bom porque retorna um chunk com todas as linhas, a partir daí você pode transformar em lista ou qualquer outro tipo. Se for um arquivo grande, você vai precisar ler as linhas uma a uma.

ii. Outra opção é usar o Numpy, que retorna um array, que possibilita várias funcionalidades no que diz respeito a manipulação de números.

```
import numpy as np
my_np_file = np.loadtxt('file.txt',delimiter = '|', dtype=str)
```

iii. Uma terceira seria o Pandas, que já foi descrito acima. Ele é muito bom pois você pode trabalhar com séries temporais e indexação de linha e coluna.

**O Numpy e o Pandas tem problemas com arrays muito grandes(~ > 2gb ), então se esse for o caso, possivelmente você tenha que escolher entre outras soluções mais específicas para esse tamanho de arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado David, o que me diz em manipular para que fique em arquivo EXCEL e no script python jogar uma formula de EXCEL para que seja editado assim que convertido ?

Comment: Cara. Eu diria pra você ficar com o python enquanto puder. Se você for mexer com o Excel mesmo, compensaria tu usar VBA. Notadamente, há uma curva de aprendizado usando o Python pra fazer essas, coisas. No entando, usando o excel no meio tu vai (i)Quebrar o fluxo de tarefas(se precisar refazer vai ser chato) e (ii)Deixar de usar as ferramentas do Python, que são muito eficientes pra isso. Se a curva de aprendizado for um problema, eu recomendo tu usar o debugger do spyder. Ele tem inspeção de variáveis, e poupa bastante paciencia pra quem ta desenvolvendo esse tipo de código procedural.